# Get ID of all items in Datatables table

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, datatables

I have the following HTML of the table

```
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade col-sm-12" id="trainerList" style="max-width: 1000px;">
    <table id="trainerListTable" class="table table-condensed table-striped" style="width: 100%;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th>Staff ID</th>
                <th>Trainer</th>
                <th>Team</th>
                <th>Department</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="listTemplateTbody"></tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

In my backbone `Initialize` function I set up a reference to my collection which calls an API to get data from the database. In this particular instance it is getting all of the rows in the staff table.

```
this.staff = options.staff;
```

In my backbone `render` function I have the following code for populating a Datatables table:

```
this.ui.listTemplateTbody.empty();

this.staff.each(function(template) {
    var profileImg = template.get('PictureUri') || "/images/placeholderUser.png";
    self.ui.listTemplateTbody.append(self.listTabletpl({
        Index: template.get('Index'),
        StaffId: template.get('Id'),
        Forename: template.get('forename'),
        Surname: template.get('surname'),
        Team: template.get('Team') || "No Team",
        Department: template.get('DepartmentId') || "No Department",
        Image: '<img class="createImageTableIcon" src="' + profileImg + '" />'
    }));
});

this.staffTable = $('#trainerListTable').DataTable({
    "aLengthMenu": [
        [5, 10, 25, 50, -1],
        [5, 10, 25, 50, "all"]
    ],
    "iDisplayLength": 10,
    "order": [
        [2, "DESC"]
    ],
    "columnDefs": [{
        "orderable": false,
        "targets": [0, 1]
    }, {
        "width": "5%",
        "targets": 0
    }, {
        "width": "5%",
        "targets": 1
    }, {
        "width": "10%",
        "targets": 2
    }, {
        "width": "40%",
        "targets": 3
    }, {
        "width": "20%",
        "targets": 4
    }, {
        "width": "20%",
        "targets": 5
    }]
});
```

In a new function I want to be able to get the `Index` of each item in `listTemplateTbody`. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
createCourseTpl: function(e) {
   //get id of each item here?
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#trainerListTable').each(function(index, domobj) {
    //your logic
});
```

Explanation:

You select your id trainerListTable and iterate through the children where as stated index gives you the number of iterations and also index of the element from parent and domobj is the child itself for example for index 0 thead  would be the dom element and so on so you can write your logic which element to manipulate and which not.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!